# python print the following output

Tags: python

Write a program that prints the following output:

10 8 6 4 2 0

8 6 4 2 0

6 4 2 0

4 2 0

2 0

0

I made this code but it doesn't work.

```
for i in range(10, -1, -2):
 print(i, "\t")

 for j in range(i, -1, -2):
    print(j, end = " ")
```

Comment: Your code has 4 lines, one of them shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few changes for the desired output:

```
for i in range(10, -1, -2):
     print("\t")
     for j in range(i, -1, -2):
        print(j, end = " ")
     print("\t")
```

Comment: @Yuka My pleasure. If you accept my answer plz tick the green tick beside my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Almost there:

```
for i in range(10, -1, -2):
    lst = list()
    for j in range(i, -1, -2):
        lst.append(j)

    print(*lst, end="\n")
```

Store the values of each line before printing, e.g. within a list.